# Why does this code in Javascript only return one value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write code that will take all of the two-digit numbers, separate them into digits, square the digits and then add them. After that it will repeat the process until a one-digit number is made.

```
for (i=11;i<25;i++) {
  var array = (i).toString(10).split("").map(Number)
  var element0 = array[0]
  var element1 = array[1]
  var total = (element0*element0)+(element1*element1)
  while (total>9) {
    array = (total).toString(10).split("").map(Number)
    element0 = array[0]
    element0 = array[1]
    total = (element0*element0)+(element1*element1)
  }
  if (total == 1) {
    console.log(i + " is correct")
  }
}
```

Whenever I run this process, the browser freezes and I have to force close it. I am new to Javascript so I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Around the 8th line, you're reassigning `element0` twice with `array[0]` and then `array[1]`. This means `element0` will always be whatever `array[1]`'s value is.

Comment: 1. Which is it? Does it "only return one value" or does it freeze? 2. Please indent your code readably when asking for help. 3. The best way to know why it's freezing (looping endlessly) is to use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser and step through the code, statement by statement, watching the values. So your best bet is to search for how to use the debugger built into your browser. (Or now to debug NodeJS, if that's where you're running this.) 4. 11-24 (inclusive) is not "all the two-digit numbers."

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your code, for example, a simple alert like this:

```
for (i=11;i<25;i++) {
var array = (i).toString(10).split("").map(Number)
var element0 = array[0]
var element1 = array[1]
var total = (element0*element0)+(element1*element1)
while (total>9) {
array = (total).toString(10).split("").map(Number)
element0 = array[0]
element0 = array[1]
total = (element0*element0)+(element1*element1)
alert(total)
}
if (total == 1) {
console.log(i + " is correct")
}
}
```

will reveal you the problem, the script keeps obtaining the same three numbers every three iterations!

P.S. it's a good practice to terminate your statements with a semicolon, even if it's not required :)

Comment: Don't debug using `alert` calls. Use the actual debugger. Heck, if you really want to bake your debug logic into your code, then just use the `debugger` keyword which will trip a breakpoint when encountered. If you don't want to use the debugger (for some reason) and/or want some feedback on what the code is doing at some point, then `console.log` (or `info`, `trace`, `warn`, `error`, etc) the information you need. Calling `alert` is a very bad way of doing stuff, it is not usable if you want to check code without modifying it and it's especially bad since it can cause or mask some bugs.

Comment: I totally agree with you in a professional contest, but since this code seems just a little exercise to me I tought for him would be good a very basic tool such an "alert" :)

Comment: I disagree. Using `alert` is not and should not be used as a basic tool because it isn't. It affects your code and what you see in more ways than comfortable and in a lot of cases it will give you wrong results if it doesn't change what your code produces. The usage of `alert` for debugging should really not be encouraged. Especially since `console.log` would give you equivalent or _better_ output with none of the drawbacks. And all you need to do is just replace one call with the other and that's it. Moreover, the log statement can just be left in and it will help in the future, too.